# hibernate generated sql query changes characters improperly

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc

DBMS - oracle 11gr2

we recently upgraded the IDE and OS of a java console application that runs 10 times a month. 
now None of our queries work properly since hibernate converts the letter i to İ which is not I. All insert statements and id fields affected negatively.
now in our queries

id -> İD not ID
insert -> İNSERT not INSERT
neither select statements nor inserts do not execute.

for example:
in the previous version Select id from table a is now sent to the db as

SELECT İD from table a ,

and we dont have such a column called İD at all.
stack trace is as follows

---

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "İD": geçersiz belirleyici (invalid identifier)

---

Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="readObject" referenceClass=OrtakEntity sql="SELECT İD, ADİ, ALACAKLARİNDAHACİZVARMİ, ANNEADİ, FROM A WHERE (İD = ?)")
********************sistem toplam sure***********************0.0
********************Time unit toplam sure***********************0
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "İD": geçersiz belirleyici

Error Code: 904
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.session

Comment: Eek, what version of hibernate?  I'm sure I logged a bug like this and it got fixed.  Hmm hibernate JIRA seems broken at this time. HTTP/404 to all POSTs.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: From Aug 2011?  Try 3.6.10.Final from Feb 2012 ?  But I don't think the fix is in there, see my bug report https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8579

Comment: Solution to keep 3.6.7.Final is obviously to use strict US-ASCII in your identifiers for variable/property/column names.  Maybe you can enforce escaping by using backquote characters in HBM or in JPA annoatations for column names.  Like ``@Column(name="`non_USASCII_id`")``

Comment: I resolved the issue by chaning the regional settings of the computer to English and United States.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing the settings of the computer to English and United States as location. (still not the best approach but now the program runs)